# Django - call view method when including template

Tags: django

Is it possible in Django to have a view method associated to template, so when I {% include %} a child template in my parent template, the child template can call it's view method and get some data? Or the only way is to have a single view method associated to url that collects data for every template?

The question is not about the template inheritance. It's more about the scenario when there are a few templates included on a single page.

Comment: Create a custom template tag and use it in your template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default there is no way to automatically call view in django when you are using `include` tag in templates.

If you want just to call some python code from inside the template, check out custom template tags. For your use case best option will be custom [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)